# v8-compile-cache-0 directory appears when deploying to Digital Ocean via Codeship

Tags: ssh, digital-ocean, codeship

I am deploying to [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) via [Codeship](https://codeship.com/). Following [this](https://hackernoon.com/continuous-deployment-for-node-js-on-digitalocean-d800e8520ffe) example, Codeship runs the following custom script in the Droplet:

```
ssh root@<MY_IP> 'cd /var/www/example/backend/; git checkout master; git pull; npm install;'
```

This all runs fine. However, when I SSH into my Droplet from my local machine, the changes are not reflected within the git repo. Instead, there is a directory called `v8-compile-cache-0`. Reading the description of [the npm package of that name](https://www.npmjs.com/package/v8-compile-cache) does not further my understanding.

What is going on here, and how do I get my pulled changes properly reflected in the Droplet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This all runs fine

Stringing together commands with semicolons may silence issues with commands that would otherwise be returning nonzero exit codes.

I'd first attempt re-running this build using double ampersands instead and then reaching out to support@codeship.com if changes are still not reflected in your droplet.

Comment: I did that, and I received a new error indicating that the password with which I was attempting to connect to my repo was incorrect. I logged into the Droplet from my local machine and saved the password using `git config credential.helper store`. In addition, I updated my script to use `git pull origin <branch>` instead of just `git pull`. These changes together lead to my desired outcome.

Since your suggestion to use double ampersands allowed me to find a solution, I'll accept this answer.